# Mostrar imagen a partir de una ruta

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

Tengo un formulario web form con un control asp:img en el cual quiero mostrar una imagen, de la cual solo dispongo la ruta completa del archivo (incluyendo el nombre de archivo) que esta almacenada en el servidor (la ruta esta guardada en una tabla en la base de datos). Pero no se como hacerlo. Hay algun ejemplo de como hacerlo, por ejemplo, incrustando codigo vb .net en la pagina aspx?

EDITO: SOLUCIONADO.

lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

Función para obtener la imagen en base64:

```
Public Function obtenerImagen(rutaOrden As String) As String

    Try

        Dim bytesImagen As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(rutaOrden)
        Dim imagenBase64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesImagen)

        Dim tipoContenido As String

        Select Case Path.GetExtension(rutaOrden)

            Case ".jpg"
                tipoContenido = "image/jpg"
            Case ".gif"
                tipoContenido = "image/gif"
            Case ".png"
                tipoContenido = "image/png"
            Case Else
                Return Nothing

        End Select

        Return String.Format("data:{0};base64,{1}", tipoContenido, imagenBase64)

    Catch

        Return Nothing

    End Try

End Function
```

Y desde aquí llamo a la función para asignar la url al control image de asp:

```
Dim rutaOrden As String = solicitud("adjunto").ToString.Trim
Dim imagenOrden As String = obtenerImagen(rutaOrden)

If imagenOrden = Nothing Then
    imgOrdenMedica.AlternateText = "Error al obtener la imagen de la orden"
    lnkOrden.Visible = False
Else
    imgOrdenMedica.ImageUrl = imagenOrden
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo en el `code-behing` de la página:

```
img.ImageUrl = "Ruta"
```

Eso sí, tendrás que tener en cuenta que esto tiene que ser una ruta relativa.

Si en tu base de datos tienes `C:/temp/foto.jpg` tendrás que **transformarla** en relativa, es decir como llegar desde la página de origen a donde esta el fichero.

Comment: Lo mejor seria guardar La imagen en la BBDD en formato BLOB, y luego coger la imagen desde el programa y transformarla a `WebControls.Image`

Comment: @Geraniego eso no es "**lo mejor**". Son distintas formas de almacenar, y mostrar, imágenes.

Comment: @AgustinM. Cierto es. Pero creo q mi opcioon es mas manejable

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas. Finalmente lo resolví convirtiendo la imagen a base64 a través de la ruta y luego asigno la misma a la url del control image de asp. Edito la pregunta para mostrar el código.